# R > EXPR > with option -e, is it possible to return only the calculated result of the given expression

Tags: r

I am new to R,

I know that R has the -e option, with which we can give an expression and immediately get the returned result, but is it possible to use R like the bash command - expr or bc, which can just return the calculated result?

Answer (score 1):

Try `R --silent` and use `cat` or `print` to write the output value. You might also look at `littler` to provide a mechanism for scripting R.